# Formal introduction of product measure

Tags: measure-theory

Having proven the existence and uniqueness of the product measure $\mu$, given two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces $(\Omega_1,\sum_1, \mu_1), (\Omega_2,\sum_2, \mu_2)$, you can extend this principle to finitely many measure spaces. For the induction step, I read that you put $\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2\times...\times \Omega_n =(\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2\times...)\times \Omega_n$, so that the n-tuples are interpreted as 2-tuples and the first case can be used again.

My question: I assume that there is not $really$ an equality between the two sets, but that one can fix this the same way as $\mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R} \cong\mathbb{R}^3$. The two vector spaces are not $really$ equal, but you can forget about that thanks to the isomorphism. What's the case with the general n-times-cartesian product? Is there again an isomorphism two define the product measure, or something similar like a bijection between $\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2\times...\times \Omega_n $ and $(\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2\times...)\times \Omega_n$, that "preserves the measure"?

I guess this kind of question falls into the section "When do we identify isomorphic copies" or so.

I hope my question is understandable and relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the (canonical) map

$$
(\Omega_1 \times \cdots \times \Omega_{n-1}) \times \Omega_n \to \Omega_1 \times \cdots \times \Omega_n, ((x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}), x_n) \mapsto (x_1, \dots, x_n).
$$

You can then take for example the [image measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) of the product measure obtained on $(\Omega_1 \times \cdots \times \Omega_{n-1}) \times \Omega_n$ to get the product measure on $\Omega_1 \times \cdots \times \Omega_n$.

But to be honest, one usually ignores these subtleties. Sometimes, $\Omega_1 \times \cdots \times \Omega_n$ is even **defined** (inductively) as $(\Omega_1 \times \cdots \times \Omega_{n-1}) \times \Omega_n$.

Comment: Thanks. The image measure is what I was looking for.